# Text with line-height has an icon at the end. How to display it proper after new-line?

Tags: html, css

I try to create a text and after the text I want to place an icon. The Icon is higher then the text and needs to vertical-center middle.

I tried different things, but as the text can go over 2 lines I run into problems. For example I use line-height = height of the icon and then put the icon as background-image to the right with some padding. But as soon as the text goes over 2 lines this does not work anymore:

Here is a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/m1ten8Ld/

As long as the text is on one line it fits perfectly: [image]

But as soon as it goes over 2 lines it doesnt work anymore: [image]

Anyone has an idea how I could solve that?

Fiddlecode:

```
div {
  background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=13&txt=150%C3%9750&w=150&h=50');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/m1ten8Ld/1/ (resize the frame to check behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can insert image via the pseudo `:after`

```css
div {
  padding-right: 150px;/* is it necessary ? */
  display: inline-block;
}
div:after {
  content: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=13&txt=150%C3%9750&w=150&h=50');
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -150px;/* necessary if padding set earlier ? */
}
```

```html
<div>This is a Text and the Icon should always be here -></div>
```

Comment: yes perfect, I was so close. I tried with :after too, but I missed the `vertical-align: middle;` Ty!

Comment: There is one more thing: What would you do if the icon is dynamic (for example created with PHP)? Would you create a style-tag in the HTML-output? In my case the icon is only semi-dynamic, so I will be able to work around this with different classes.

Comment: Yes, if your icon is dynamic, insert it in a tag right after text content is inserted, else you could isert a style tag with the CSS and the attribute scoped( https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/style )

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand your question. You can achieve the result with CSS `:before` or `:after` selectors as shown below. I suggest you use fontAwesome or similar icon font.

```css
div {
  background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=13&txt=150%C3%9750&w=150&h=50');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "\f013";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  float: left;
  position: realtive;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px; /* Adjust as needed */
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
This is a Text and the Icon should always be here ->
</div>
```

[>> fontAwesome cheat-sheet.](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)